# applying changes to a model in angular.js that was fetched by scope.$apply

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive in AngularJS that fetches an array like so:

```
var current_element_list = scope.$apply($(this).attr('sortable-model'));
```

The rest of the code looks something like this:

```
//in the controller
$scope.project.elements = [];

//in the html
<customDirective sortable-model='project.elements'>
```

I thought that scope.$apply would return a reference to `$scope.project.elements` array, so that any changes I made in the directive would be retained in that model. However, this does not seem to be the case, as any changes I made to the array are not saved. Is there anyway I can save changes back to the array in the root scope from here that I obtained via the `sortable-model` attribute?

Comment: You'll want to check out [this](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) part of the docs which talks about directives, specifically the "scope" section.

Answer (score 1):

When you want bi-directional binding between a directive and controller scope, you should use the `scope` property when defining the directive.

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("Ctrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.project = {
        elements: [1, 2, 3]
    };
});

app.directive("customDirective", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            sortableModel: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // Access the controller's scope.project.elements here as scope.sortableModel
            console.log(scope.sortableModel);

            // Changes to scope.sortableModel will also affect the controller's scope.project.elements
            scope.sortableModel.push(4);
        }
    };
});
```

See a [working fiddle in action](http://jsfiddle.net/lolson/uvn9p/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up an isolate scope and map your model value to a local in your directive.

From the Angularjs directive scope documentation:

> = or =attr - set up bi-directional binding between a local scope property and the parent scope property of name defined via the value of the attr attribute. If no attr name is specified then the attribute name is assumed to be the same as the local name. Given  and widget definition of scope: { localModel:'=myAttr' }, then widget scope property localModel will reflect the value of parentModel on the parent scope. Any changes to parentModel will be reflected in localModel and any changes in localModel will reflect in parentModel.

```
angular("app")
  .directive('customDirective ', function () {
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
           scope.localModel.push("New Element");
       }, 
       scope:{
           localModel: '=sortableModel',
       }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

### Answer to your question

Having the changes to the array in the directive be reflected in the original should work since standard prototype inheritance rules apply. Meaning in your directive (even if it creates a new scope) when you do this:

```
current_element_list[0] = 'new value';
```

That change should be reflected in the controller's `$scope.project.elements` variable.

Now **if your directive does NOT create a new scope**, the `scope` variable passed to the directive should be the same as the `$scope` of the containing controller, meaning you should just be able to change whatever is on that scope directly as you please. So if you do this in the directive:

```
scope.project.elements = ['new value'];
```

That change should also be reflected in the controller's `$scope.project.elements` variable.

**If your directive creates an isolated scope**, then you shouldn't be using `scope.$apply($(this).attr('sortable-model'))` to get the evaluated value of the attribute. Instead you will use:

```
scope : {
    current_element_list : '=sortableModel'
}
```

This creates a two-way data binding to the evaluated value of sortableModel, and is made accessible to your directive now through `scope.current_element_list`.

---

### Suggested Improvements to your code

With regards to this line:

```
var current_element_list = scope.$apply($(this).attr('sortable-model'));
```

If you simply want to "fetch" the array, you do not need use `$apply`, instead you would use `$eval`. The `$apply` function is primarily used to bring one back to the AngularJS context, triggering the digest loop and checking that all the models are balanced and all changes are accounted for. `$eval` (which the `$apply` function calls) simply evaluates a given expression on the given scope.

Also, with directives you shouldn't ever have to use jQuery to fetch attribute names or values, or even the element itself. The linking function gets passed 4 arguments, one of them being an object with the attribute and attribute values of said element. A directive's controller can be injected with the $attrs service as well which will return the same thing. [(read directive documentation)](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Here is the above code redone:

```
link : function(scope, element, attrs, controllers) {
    // ...
    var current_element_list = scope.$eval(attrs['sortable-model']);
    // ...
}
```